# @Html.EnumDropDownListFor searchable, how to do it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make the helper `@Html.EnumDropDownListFor` searchable with an input tag on it. That way I can type to search for an item in the huge list. I preferably want to make this hard coded without other plugins. Can someone help me?

Here is the code:

```
<div>Escolha aqui o banco de sua preferência:</div>
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.BankPaymentMethods, " ", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "form-control"})
```

Comment: `hardcode without others plugins.` but you're still fine with javascript or jquery right? I doubt this is possible without those. Also, I think you'll need to have the script separately rendered-- not inside your dropdownlist.

Comment: You can do it directly with Jquery-UI lib. Please paste your code and the models, actions.

Comment: @JerdineSabio, yes i`m still fine with javascript and jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Typically its done inside a `text box`, I guess you can do it inside a Select by appending the `value and name` also you need to paste your VM or `selectList` VMModel. I have made some assumptions, code is not tested, but with a couple change and hopefully it will help you.

---

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BankPaymentID)  
@section scripts{  
// you can update to the latest version of Jquery-ui, I put in the most compatible version for you
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.15.1.js">script>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.15.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">  
    <script>  
        $(function () {  
            $("#BankPaymentID").autocomplete({  
                source: function (request, response) {  
                $.ajax({  
                    url: '@Url.Action("Searchable")',  // server action
                    datatype: "json",  
                    data: {  
                        term: request.term             // this what you are searching
                    },  
                    success: function (data) {  
                        response($.map(data, function (val, item) {  
                            return {  
                                label: val.Name,  
                                value: val.Name,  
                                BankPaymentID: val.ID  
                            }  
                        }))  
                    }  
                })  
            },  
            select: function (event, ui) {  
                $.get("/Home/GetBankPaymentMethods", { BankPaymentID: ui.item.BankPaymentID }, function (data) {  
                    $("#PaymentID").empty();  
                    $.each(data, function (index, row) {  
                        $("#PaymentID").append("<option value='" + row.PaymentID + "'>" + row.PaymentName + "option>")  
                    });  

                });  
            }  
            })  
        })  
    script>  
}
```

---

Controller `Searchable` Action

```
public ActionResult Searchable(string term)  
{  
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(term))  
    {  
        var list = db.banks.Where(c=>c.PaymentName.ToUpper().Contains(term.ToUpper())).Select(c => new { Name = c.PaymentName, ID = c.BankPaymentID })  
            .ToList();  
        return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        var list = db.banks.Select(c => new { Name = c.PaymentName, ID = c.BankPaymentID })  
            .ToList();  
        return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  
    }  
}
```

Comment: @Osvaldo Please mark as answer if you were able to use it :)

Comment: Can you paste your code, so we can look through the issue

Answer (score 1):

[The EnumDropDownListFor  helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.enumdropdownlistfor) only generates `<select>` elements. The closest you can get without a plugin would be an input with a datalist and the `list` attribute.

Assuming your enum is called `BankPaymentMethod` and `BankPaymentMethods` is an IEnumerable of some sort, and your model has a `PaymentMethod` property:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PaymentMethod, new { @class = "form-control", list = "payment-methods" })
<datalist id="payment-methods">
    @foreach(var method in Model.BankPaymentMethods)
    {
        <option value="@method">@method</option>
    }
</datalist>
```

For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist.

Comment: Tieson, thank you! It was the closest i could get, but still not working.